# How to set adapter of spinner by using Async Task Class

Tags: android

In my code I load a spinner adapter by using Async Task 
    In My case The ProgressDialog is Not dismissing 
    This is My code. 
    I want to show the item after adapter load and the progressDialog is to dismiss
    Please Help me, Thanks

```
private class LoadMoreVehicals extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(RegistrationScreen.this, "",
                    "Loading...");
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.anim.progressbar_handler));
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            String countryUrl = ConstantURL.COUNTRY_URL;
            getCounty(countryUrl);

            countrySpinner
            .setAdapter(new MyCustomSpinnerAdapter(
                    RegistrationScreen.this,
                    R.layout.spinner_dropdown,
                    countyList));

                                return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            progressBar.getProgress();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

            progressBar.dismiss();

             Log.e("Im in onPostExecute", "");
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience i have so many problems with async runs and UI so now always separate the stuff trying to place the "responsibilities" in each place. So i do something like this:

1. Create my Async class with the process i want to do and nothing that transform the UI in it
2. Create a function in UI thread that modify the UI when async task finish, something like OnAsyncTaskComplete(Object response)
3. Keep communicated the threads

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity {

   private static MyAsyncClass backgroundTask;
   private static ProgressDialog pleaseWaitDialog; 

   //......activity stuff.......

   @Override
   public void onPause()
   {
       super.onPause();
       //Get rid of progress dialog in the event of a screen rotation or other state change. Prevents a crash.
       if (pleaseWaitDialog != null)
           pleaseWaitDialog.dismiss();
   }
   //Function to avoid lose the async thread if the app interrupts (phone rotation, incoming call, etc) RECOMENDED TO HANDLE THIS!!
   //Sets the current state after app resume
   @Override
   public void onResume()
   {

       super.onResume();
       //If there is a background task set it to the new activity
       if ((backgroundTask != null) && (backgroundTask.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING))
       {
          if (pleaseWaitDialog != null)
            pleaseWaitDialog.show();

          backgroundTask.setActivity(this);
       }
       }
   }

       //Logic business after the web service complete here
   //Do the thing that modify the UI in a function like this
   private void onTaskCompleted(Object _response) 
   { 
       //For example _response can be a new adapter
   MyList.setAdapter((BaseAdapter)_response);
   //or can be a list to create the new adapter
   MyList.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, (ArrayList<String>)_response));
   //or can be anything you want, just try to make here the things that you need to change the UI
   }

   /**
    * Class that handle the async task
    */
   public class MyAsyncClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object>
   {
       //Maintain attached activity for states change propose 
        private MyActivity activity;
        //Keep the response of the async task
        private Object _response;
        //Flag that keep async task completed status
        private boolean completed; 

        //Constructor
        private MyAsyncClass(MyActivity activity) { 
                this.activity = activity;
        } 

        //Pre execution actions
        @Override 
        protected void onPreExecute() {
                //Start the splash screen dialog
                if (pleaseWaitDialog == null)
                    pleaseWaitDialog= ProgressDialog.show(activity.this, 
                                                           "PLEASE WAIT", 
                                                           "Getting results...", 
                                                           false);

        } 

        //Execution of the async task
       protected Object doInBackground(Object...params)
       {
           //return the thing you want or do want you want
           return new ArrayList();
       }

       //Post execution actions
       @Override 
       protected void onPostExecute(Object response) 
       {
           //Set task completed and notify the activity
               completed = true;
               _response = response;
               notifyActivityTaskCompleted();
           //Close the splash screen
           if (pleaseWaitDialog != null)
           {
               pleaseWaitDialog.dismiss();
               pleaseWaitDialog = null;
           }
       } 

       //Notify activity of async task completion
       private void notifyActivityTaskCompleted() 
       { 
           if ( null != activity ) { 
               activity.onTaskCompleted(_response); 
           } 
       } 

   //for maintain attached the async task to the activity in phone states changes
       //Sets the current activity to the async task
       public void setActivity(MyActivity activity) 
       { 
           this.activity = activity; 
           if ( completed ) { 
               notifyActivityTaskCompleted(); 
           } 
       } 

   }
   }
   ```

Hope its help you

Comment: as basic model to make async task it works perfect for me until now, just adapt it to the need of each app and go, happy to help

Answer (score 2):

While programming in Android you should remember one thing that any task which draws something on the screen should be executed on the **main thread**. When you set the adapter then android calls the getView() method of the adapter and draws views on the screen. So you should set the adapter in the postExecute() method instead in doInBackground() method. 
Here is a small sample to clear my point:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute ( )
    {
        //starting the progress dialogue
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground (Void... params)
    {
        //fetch data here
        ...
        ... 
        return null;
    }

            @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Void result)
    {
        //set adapter here
        ...
        ...
        //dismissing the progress dialogue
        pd.dismiss();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot set the adapter in the `doInBackground`
follow this design:

```
private class LoadMoreVehicals extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> 
{
    private ArrayList<Country> countries;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(RegistrationScreen.this, "","Loading...");
         progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
         progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.anim.progressbar_handler));              
         super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String countryUrl = ConstantURL.COUNTRY_URL;
        countries = getCounty(countryUrl);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        progressBar.getProgress();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        countrySpinner.setAdapter(new MyCustomSpinnerAdapter(RegistrationScreen.this,R.layout.spinner_dropdown,countries));
        progressBar.dismiss();
        Log.e("Im in onPostExecute", "");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not Working still ProgressDialog is not dismissing